# Creating a menu option in google docs using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to use google apps script to create the Automated Sharing option in the google docs menu but it doesn't show up. How to get it to run?

I am completely out of my league here but trying to automate a process using this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4179ndy_AM

```
function onOpen() {
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    createMenu("Automated Sharing")
    .additem("Share file now", "shareFile")
    .addToUi();
}
```

Was expecting a menu item in google sheets and nothing happened.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and `Trying to use google apps script to create the Automated Sharing option in the google docs menu but it doesn't show up. How to get it to run?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a period `.` at the end of the `getUi()`.  You need to chain `createMenu()` to the `ui`.

**Change**

```
function onOpen() {
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    createMenu("Automated Sharing")
    .additem("Share file now", "shareFile")
    .addToUi();
}
```

**To**

```
function onOpen() {
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("Automated Sharing")
    .additem("Share file now", "shareFile")
    .addToUi();
}
```

**Reference**

- [Ui.createMenu()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#createMenu(String))